# why cant I only access a port from localhost?

Tags: firewall, port, hadoop

I am trying to set up elasticsearch on my mapR issued redhat virtual machine. It comes pre-loaded with the mapR ecosystem. I installed elasticsearch via yum.

I am able to listen to it from inside the vm:

```
[root@maprdemo elasticsearch]# curl -XGET 'localhost:8080/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "QYCiQJi",
  "cluster_name" : "sdc-search",
  "cluster_uuid" : "bMSLPA3uR5WKbtwKP0Sl7g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "080bb47",
    "build_date" : "2016-11-11T22:08:49.812Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

...but not from outside the machine. I can access other ports it's broadcasting though such as the HUE UI from outside the VM, so I believe there is some firewall issue.

I have no iptables rules defined:

```
[root@maprdemo elasticsearch]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Something I noticed debuging:

```
[root@maprdemo elasticsearch]# netstat -anp | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 :::18080                    :::*                        LISTEN      16987/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*                        LISTEN      31852/java

//A Port im able to access from outside the machine fine
[root@maprdemo elasticsearch]# netstat -anp | grep 8443
tcp        0      0 :::8443                     :::*                        LISTEN      13569/java
```

The port I can view outside the machine (8443) looks a little different when checking netstat.

I'm simply not sure where else to be debugging. If anyone can point me in a direction for figuring this issue that would be great. I'm only a developer and my knowledge of networking is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You are only seeing the default iptables filter with the command you used, so it is still possible that it is at play. Take a look at the very well worded responses in this thread for the iptables options (really quick try 'iptables -S' which I believe should show you everything): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205867/viewing-all-iptables-rules

If not iptables, sometimes selinux causes mischief so disabling it while you test might be an option ('setenforce 0'). You can verify that current status with 'sestatus'. To enable again use 'setenforce 1' or rebooting will re-enable.

Last but not least, and as I type this I realize this might be the answer, verify what IP the service is actually listening on. I am not familiar with that application but in general you can actually have a service listening on a given port only for local connections, so it may just be a configuration change that you need. In fact in re-reading your post the presence of the loopback address (127.0.0.1) in the netstat output for port 8080 you posted makes me wonder if that is what is happening.